# split a string into letters and digits in c

Tags: c, string, split

I want to write a code to split the numbers and characters in this pattern by finding finding the position of first digit and alphabet and **using `strcpy` and `strncpy`** in c

input:

`ATL1203S14`

output:

```
warehouse: ATL

product: 1203

Qualifiers: S14
```

The **warehouse** has only alphabet and **product** has only number but **qualifiers** starts with a capital letter and its following digits. but the input can vary in the number of digits and alphabets.

so basically i wanted to flag the first character and digit in the input and then copy them into a new string but it doesn't give me the **warehouse** output and also i didn't have any idea on how to identify the **Qualifiers**.

so I would be very thankful and happy if anybody can help me with the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MMOC_len 20

int main()
{
    char MMOC_cod[MMOC_len];
    char warehouse[MMOC_len];
    char productNo[MMOC_len];
    char qualifiers[MMOC_len];
    int current, next, Ch_ind, No_ind;

    printf("Hello World enter your MMOC like >ATL1203S14< \n");
    scanf("%s", MMOC_cod);

    for (current=0; current<= strlen(MMOC_cod); current++)
    {
        if(MMOC_cod[current] >= '0' && MMOC_cod[current] <='9')
        {
            No_ind= current;
            break;
        }

        else if(MMOC_cod[current] >= 'A' && MMOC_cod[current] <='Z')
        {
            Ch_ind= current;
            break;
        }
    }
            strncpy(productNo, &MMOC_cod[current], (Ch_ind - No_ind-1));
            productNo[No_ind-1]= '\0';
            printf("product Number: %s", productNo);

            /// the warehouse part doesn't work also
            /// I cant set condition for Qualifiers as well but I cant find the problem
            strncpy(warehouse, &MMOC_cod[0], (No_ind-1));
            warehouse[No_ind-Ch_ind]= '\0';
            printf("warehouse: %s", warehouse);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Rather than check the inequalities ≥ '', ≤ '', etc., you could use the isalpha and isdigit functions from the standard library. They're in ctype.h.

Comment: oh thank you. i wasnt sure about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you write `current<= strlen(MMOC_cod)` but you have to remember that you should iterate while current is strictly inferior to strlen(MMOC_cod) since you start at index 0.

I prefer to use `memcpy` when I know the length:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define BUFF_SIZE 256

int main()
{
    char s[BUFF_SIZE];
    char warehouse[BUFF_SIZE];
    char productNo[BUFF_SIZE];
    char qualifiers[BUFF_SIZE];

    printf("Hello World enter your MMOC like >ATL1203S14< \n");
    scanf("%s", s);
    int n = strlen(s);
    if (n > BUFF_SIZE)
        return 1;
    int i = 0;
    while (isalpha((unsigned char)s[i])) {
        warehouse[i] = s[i];
        i++;
    }
    warehouse[i] = '\0';
    int j = 0;
    while (isdigit((unsigned char)s[i]))
        productNo[j++] = s[i++];
    productNo[j] = '\0';
    memcpy(qualifiers,&s[i],n-i);
    qualifiers[n-i] = '\0';

    printf("warehouse: %s\n", warehouse);
    printf("product Number: %s\n", productNo);
    printf("qualifiers: %s\n", qualifiers);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Output:

```
warehouse: ATL
product Number: 1203
qualifiers: S14
```

*NB: If you receive an input of length superior to BUFF_SIZE your program will return.*

Answer (score 2):

You are making things difficult on yourself. This is a circumstance where a well-crafted *format-string* for `sscanf()` can separate the input into the values for `warehouse`, `product` and `qualifiers` you need, e.g.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define SUBSTRSZ 32         /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (void) {
    
    char *input = "ATL1203S14";                         /* input */
    char warehouse[SUBSTRSZ], qualifiers[SUBSTRSZ];     /* string storage */
    unsigned product;                                   /* treat product as unsigned */
    
    /* separate input into warehouse, product & qualifiers, VALIDATE the conversion */
    if (sscanf (input, " %31[^0-9] %u %31[^\n]", warehouse, &product, qualifiers) != 3) {
        fputs ("error: invalid input format.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    
    printf ("warehouse: %s\nproduct: %u\nQualifiers: %s\n",
            warehouse, product, qualifiers);
}
```

The format-string `" %31[^0-9] %u %31[^\n]"`:

- `" "` discards leading whitespace, if any, because `"%c"` and `"%[..]"` do not do it on their own,
- `%31[^0-9]` reads up to a max of 31-chars (preserving room for `'\0'` protecting your array bounds) that are not digits,
- `%u` unsigned conversion to handle up to 10-digits (adjust type to `uint64_t` if more digits needed or to `uint32_t` if `unsigned` less than 32 bits on your system), You can also change `product` to a string and use use `%31[0-9]` if you prefer handling it that way,
- `%31[^\n]` read remainder of line up to max of 31 chars.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/splitcode
warehouse: ATL
product: 1203
Qualifiers: S14
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: thank you for answering. I just have this question. why is it !=3 in if part I just isn't get that.
and thank you very much again

Comment: That is one of he benefits of using `sscanf()` here. It doesn't matter how many characters `warehouse`, `product`, or `qualifier` have, so long as `warehouse` are alpha-characters, `product` are digits and `qualifiers` begins with a non-digit, this will separate them properly. For example, if your `input` were `"ATLANTA1203471S14001"` you would get `"ATLANTA"`, `203471` and `"S14001"` .